# Цвет контейнера (–) иссиня-изжелта-зелёный

Tags: тире

Нужно тире?

`1. Какой цвет у стены?`

`Цвет (–) белый.`

А здесь?

`2. Цвет контейнера (–) иссиня-изжелта-зелёный.`

Comment: Я разочарую, но иссиня-изжелтый цвет получить не получится - цвета противоположные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[По Розенталю, пункт 10](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92#pp92):**

Тире перед именной частью сказуемого, выраженного **прилагательным**, обычно не ставится, но его можно поставить для обозначения увеличенной паузы.  В этом случае ударение падает **на подлежащее** для его логического подчеркивания. Выбор делается по контексту.

**Разговор  с художником**

**Вариант (1)**

*— Какой цвет у стены?*

*— ЦвЕт – **белый**, какие сомнения? Или ты его синим видишь?*

**Вариант (2)**

— *ЦвЕт контейнера – **иссиня-изжелта-зелёный***. Красиво!

— *Он серый на самом деле. Это его бензинчиком случайно облили*.